# Confused by "orthogonal representation" of a finite group. How to show the matrix under some basis from the new defined inner product is orthogonal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose we have a finite group $G$ and a representation $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ on the finite vector space $V$. So $V$ is a $G$-module.

Now I am asked to show that there is a basis of $V$ under which the matrix of $\rho(g)$ is orthogonal for all $g\in G$. Here is what confused me and I still don't know in what sense is this possible. I have done some searching and know typically the steps are the following:(here we assume $\rho(g)$ is the matrix under standard basis)

(1) Define a $G$-invariant inner product $[v,w]=\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g)v,\rho(g)w\rangle$, where $\langle,\rangle$ is the usual inner product under standard basis.
(2) Choose a basis of $V$ that is orthogonal w.r.t this inner product.
(3) Under such basis, the matrix of $\rho(g)$ is orthogonal for all $g\in G$.

Questions: does the (2) mean we find a matrix $B$ s.t. $B^H\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)^H\rho(g)B=I$? If yes, then the matrix of $\rho(g)$ under the basis $B$ should become $M(g)=B^{-1}\rho(g)B$ right? But how could we see $M(g)^HM(g)=I$?

I guess I must be misunderstanding somewhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I think I got this. I was stupid. I think in this way: if let $\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)^H\rho(g)=Q^HQ$ positive definiteness, then for each $g\in G$ we have $\rho(g)^HQ^HQ\rho(g)=Q^HQ$ from $G$-invariance. Then this shows $Q\rho(g)Q^{-1}$ is unitary(orthogonal). Now let $B=Q^{-1}$ then we are done. This is is the same as the one in (2).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm misunderstanding your question, but (2) means we find vectors $\{w_i\} \subset V$ such that $[w_i, w_j] = \delta_{ij}$. In other words, $[w_i, w_j] = 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $[w_i, w_i] = 1$. This is done with the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

**Update**: I'm having trouble understanding your notation and the matrix $B$. But maybe if I put (3) in my notation then you can translate?

Note that by $G$-invariance, for all $w_1, w_2 \in V$ we have
$$[\rho(g)w_1, w_2] = [w_1, \rho(g^{-1})w_2] = [w_1, \rho(g)^{-1}w_2].$$
Moreover, the Hermitian transpose satisfies
$$[\rho(g)w_1, w_2] = [w_1, \rho(g)^H w_2]$$
In other words
$$[w_1, \rho(g)^{-1}w_2] = [w_1, \rho(g)^H w_2].$$

Now plugging in the $G$-invariant basis from (2), you can get the equality of the matrices $\rho(g)^{-1}$ and $\rho(g)^H$

Comment: I think this is the same as what I describe in (2) if you treat $B$ consists of columns of your $w_i,w_j$.

Comment: I took another crack at it based on your comment -- hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I think I know it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma\in G$. Then for all $v$, $w\in V$ one has
$$
[\rho(\gamma)v,\rho(\gamma)w]=
\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g\gamma)v,\rho(g\gamma)w\rangle=
\sum_{g^\prime\in G}\langle\rho(g^\prime)v,\rho(g^\prime)w\rangle=
[v,w]
$$
because the map $g\mapsto g\gamma$ is a bijection of $G$ onto itself.

But the above equality tells exactly that $\rho(g)$ leaves $[\cdot,\cdot]$ unchanged, so that its associated matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis will be orthogonal

Comment: Yes this is the part I understand. I always suppose this is the way we explain literally the "orthogonality" of the matrix. But I fail to really showing this in the formulaic sense like $M^HM=I$. Isn't this the mathematical definition of a orthogonal matrix(in this particular question)?

Comment: @gnon: I'm not sure about your notation $M^H$ (I assume that denotes transposition), but yes: the matrix of an orthogonal transformation has that property if written in terms of an orthonormal basis (making it an orthogonal matrix,definitions are consistent). Writing $M$ explicitly from the original matrix of $\rho$ looks cumbersome, but is not such a deep problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. I got it now. Thanks!